# Pointers and dynamic memory allocation in c

Tags: c, file-io, malloc

im reading lines from an input text file and i'm storing the lines in an array *array1*
once im done reading id like to print out the elements in the array.. id like to do dynamic memory allocation.. but thats after i get this part working..
my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LEN 256

int main(){

  FILE* fp;
  fp=fopen("input.txt","r");
  char currentline[MAX_LEN];
  int i=0;

  char *array1;
  array1 = malloc(10*MAX_LEN);
  while(fgets(currentline,MAX_LEN,fp)!=NULL && i<10){

    strcpy((char *)&array1[i],currentline);
    printf("%s\n",currentline);

    printf("array1= %s\n",(&array1[i]));
    i++;
  }
  for (;i>=0;i--){
    printf("%s\n",(&array1[i]));
  }
}
```

**input1.txt**

```
101
84
65
13
hello
90
24
94
73
70
68
94
65
```

output:

```
101

array1= 101

84

array1= 84

65

array1= 65

13

array1= 13

hello

array1= hello

90

array1= 90

24

array1= 24

94

array1= 94

73

array1= 73

70

array1= 70

0

70

770

9770

29770

929770

h929770

1h929770

61h929770

861h929770

1861h929770
```

what i want it to do is print out each element..but its printing the first character of each line.. whats causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
    strcpy((char *)&array1[i],currentline);
```

you copy currentline to the to the array1, starting at its i-th element.
So basically you first copy currentLine starting at `array[0]`, then leave first element and copy next currentLine starting at `array[1]` and so on. Every time you overwrite previous currentLine except its first element.
What you want (I suppose) to do is:

```
    strcpy(&array1[i*MAX_LEN],currentline);
```

which will save every currentLine in its own block of 256 characters.
For i=0 you will write starting at array[0],
for i=1 at array[256]...

Also drop those ugly (char *) casts, they are unnecessary in here.
You should check if malloc worked before dereferencing array1, too

Comment: aha! that clears things up alot!! thanks!! 
i put the (char *) there because of compiler warning but now it seems to be happy without them! :O